# SDL_mixer: Mix_LoadMUS not working

Tags: sdl-2, sdl-mixer

So when I load a music like this:

```
Mix_Music *musique = Mix_LoadMUS("../Resources/Mr. Trololo original upload.mp3");
Mix_PlayMusic(musique, -1);
```

It returns NULL and plays no sound.

But if I load a wav using the same path:

```
Mix_Chunk *fail = Mix_LoadWAV("../Resources/Cartoonish Sound 2.wav");
```

It plays sound.

The worse thing in all of this is that it was working before and I did not touch this part of the code.

Cans someone please help me, I'll be very grateful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works:

```
Mix_Music *musique = Mix_LoadMUS("/../Resources/Mr. Trololo original upload.mp3");
```

sorry for your time that was stupid of me...